# PDO - Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to obtain the value of the 'level' field which is of type varchar but it says that I am trying to obtain an array

This is my code

```
<?php
include("./db.php");

$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nivel FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario");
$sentencia->bindParam(":usuario", $_SESSION['usuario']);
$sentencia->execute();

$registro = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
$registro["nivel"];

?>
<?php include("plantillas/header.php"); ?>

</br>
<style>
  body {
        background-image: url('https://png.pngtree.com/background/20211217/original/pngtree-geometric-pattern-white-gold-minimalist-creative-background-picture-image_1575961.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
</style>
<br><br><br><br>
<div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3 bg-dark text-white" >
  <div class="container-fluid py-5" >
    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">Bienvenid@ al Sistema</h1>
    <p class="col-md-8 fs-4">Usuario : <?php echo  $_SESSION['usuario'];?></p>
    <p class="col-md-8 fs-4">Nivel de usuario : <?php echo  $nivel;?></p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="./confeti.php" type="button" target="_blank"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<?php include("plantillas/footer.php"); ?>
```

I am trying to get the value of the name field to display it in the paragraph.

This question has been associated with another one that is not the cause of my error, since the solution was to put the line that includes the header above the other PHP block since the header is where the active session is managed, and if it is below where the user level is requested is the reason for the error
this is the corrected code:

```
<?php include("plantillas/header.php"); ?>
<?php
include("./db.php");

$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nivel FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario");
$sentencia->bindParam(":usuario", $_SESSION['usuario']);
$sentencia->execute();

$registro = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
$registro["nivel"];

?>
```

Comment: `it says that I am trying to obtain an array`....no, that's not what it says. It says that the variable you're trying to access using array syntax (e.g. `$x["y"]`) is actually a bool (i.e. true or false). This will be because `$registro` is `false` - as per [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) PDO's `fetch()` returns `false` when there are no (more) rows to  fetch. Therefore you can't execute `$registro["nivel"]` because `$registro` isn't an array. _That's_ what the error means.

Comment: In other words, this happens if the username doesn't exist. You need to check if the query finds anything before trying to use the result.

Comment: But the root cause of this of course, is that your SQL query returned no rows, and you didn't verify this in your code, you just assumed that it did, and tried to read the row data which doesn't exist. Therefore, it must be because there are no rows in the database where the `usario` column's value matches whatever (if anyting!) is contains in `$_SESSION['usuario']`. So please go and test that this Session value contains what you expected it to, first of all, and then double-check what's in your database table. And then consider modifying your code to deal with the "no rows returned" scenario.

Comment: `bindParam(":usuario", $_SESSION['usuario']);` Are you auto-starting sessions or start your session in the included file? If not, `$_SESSION['usuario']` will not be set

Comment: @ADyson I have the `$_SESSION['usuario']` in a login file, and the field `nivel` has values in it , maybe this line is the problem? `if($registro["n_usuario"]>0){
        //guardamos ususario
        $_SESSION['usuario']=$registro["usuario"];
        $_SESSION['logueado']=true; <- this line is the problem?
        //redireccionamos
        header("Location:index.php");
    }else{//si no hay usuario
$mensaje = "Error: El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos";}`

Comment: `$_SESSION['logueado']=true; <- this line is the problem?`...why would that be the problem? The error message came from `$registro["nivel"];` in the code you posted in the question. It has no link to `$_SESSION['logueado']`. No, I think the problem is that, when you run this line: `$sentencia->bindParam(":usuario", $_SESSION['usuario']);`, at that time `$_SESSION['usuario']` has no value in it. Did you put `session_start();` anywhere in your code before that line? If you didn't, then you can't read anything from the session.

Comment: @ADyson putting the `session_start(); shows the level of the user as I spected but a new error appeared: ´session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppCurso\plantillas\header.php on line 2´ , In my header I already had a ´session_start();´ wich I use to block the app if there is not a user loged in

Comment: The problem is that header.php comes _after_ where you are using the session, so it's too late to start the session there.  The best solution though is simply to move the code which includes the header.php to the start of your script

Comment: @ADyson Moving the code allows you to enter any part of the app from the login, skipping the login, but I have already found the solution, put the line '<?php include("templates/header.php"); ?>' above the '<?php block
include("./db.php");

$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT level FROM users WHERE user=:user");
$statement->bindParam(":user", $_SESSION['user']);
$statement->execute();

$list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>'

Comment: That's what I was suggesting. Did you think I meant something else?

Comment: @ADyson no no haha, when you said "header.php comes after where you are using the session" i tried 2 ways, put the header code referencing session in the login (this worked 50/50) and put the include header tag before the php block (this was the perfect solution)

Comment: OK I see. Well I'm glad we managed to fix it